# Java8 streams strange behavior

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I was benchmarking some Java8 Streams API snippets, but I could not figure out what is happening with this one.

I was thinking about `ParallelStream` and how it actually works and trying to make some comparisons between sequential and parallel processing.
I created two different methods, both doing a huge iteration while adding 32.768.000 `BigDecimal`s, one of them using `ParallelStream`, and the other using normal sequential iteration. I ended with a test I know is not valid, but some points caught my attention.

The methods are:

```
private static void sumWithParallelStream() {
    BigDecimal[] list = new BigDecimal[32_768_000];
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32_768_000; i++) {
        list[i] = new BigDecimal(i);
    }
    total = Arrays.asList(list).parallelStream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
}

private static void sequenceSum() {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32_768_000; i++) {
        total = total.add(new BigDecimal(i));
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
}
```

The output was:

```
Total: 536870895616000
sumWithParallelStream(): 30502 ms

Total: 536870895616000
sequenceSum(): 271 ms
```

Then I tried removing the `ParallelStream` and check it's real impact:

```
 private static void sumWithParallelStream() {
    BigDecimal[] list = new BigDecimal[32_768_000];
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32_768_000; i++) {
        list[i] = new BigDecimal(i);
        total = total.add(list[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Total: " + total);
}
```

**Pay attention the `sequenceSum()` method remains unchanged**

And surprisingly, the new output was:

```
Total: 536870895616000
sumWithParallelStream(): 13487 ms

Total: 536870895616000
sequenceSum(): 879 ms
```

I repeated these changes several times, adding and removing the `parallelStream` call, and the results of `sequenceSum()` are consistent, ~200ms when `parallelStream` is involved, ~800ms when not. Tested in different machines, Windows and Ubuntu.

Finally, my two questions are:

1. Why does the usage of `parallelStream` on the first method interfere with the second one?
2. Why did store the `BigDecimal` instances in the array made the first method much slower (800ms to 13000ms)?

Comment: Try calling the methods in the other order. First `sequenceSum()` and then `sumWithParallelStream()`.

Comment: You do two very different things. When you use the parallel method you have a additional iteration over the entire list. Of course that takes longer.

Comment: @Nitram I believe he was asking why the other method affects the runtime of `sequenceSum()`. For which I'd say "JIT probably".

Comment: adding on the "JIT probably"-train of arguments: when generating new objects in a loop body it makes **all the difference** if you store that object to an array external to the loop (JIT will probably allocate each object in memory) or not (JIT will probably re-use a single allocated object in the loop body)

Comment: @Jean Jung if you want to improve your performance measure make sure that every path of code you're trying to measure is run a few thousand times before measuring it (so that the JIT has time to optimize high-performance parts)

Comment: @Kayaman is rigth, my question is about why one method affects execution of the other. Changing the order always the same result, about 200 ms.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios, thank you for your comment, but i don't understand, if the JIT will probaly use the allocated objects, why is different to `sequenceSum()` if `sumWithParallelStream()` uses `parallelStream` or not? And, they are different methods, in this case, JIT can share the objects, between different methods?

Comment: @JeanJung JIT can do anything it likes as long as the semantics of your code is not impaired - that includes interpreting code as byte code, or compiling it to native when it sees a possible gain, re-using small memory allocations for the same local (non-escaping object), allocating memory on the stack instead of the heap (again for non-escaping objects), etc...

Comment: An array of 32M BigDecimals requires lots of memory. GC must be the issue. Rerun the test case with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`.

Comment: @apangin You are rigth man, GC is the issue. Running this with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` i can see that, with `parallelStream` more memory is allocated in the initialization of Streams API and much more allocation operations is needed, then GC goes worst. Makes some sense now, thanks!

Comment: @JeanJung how about writing an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by @apangin, the issue is with the Garbage Collector.

I added the `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` command line parameter that enables execution time printing for each GC run. I could then confirm that when using `parallelStream` GC was taking more time to run, probably because of the Streams API initialization and warmup consuming more memory and leaving some trash to be collected.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you are allocating an array of 32,768,000 elements then streaming over it.  That array allocation and memory fetching isn't needed and is probably what's slowing the method down.

```
IntStream.range(0, limit).parallel()
   .mapToObj(BigDecimal::new)
   .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: wow...can't believe I have been coding in java 8 for a while and totally missed that function, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the answer here is on comments, I will write an answer.